# Experimentally measuring coherence length of laser

Tags: optics, experimental-technique

So I am trying to figure out the coherence length of my laser source.  I am using a mach zehnder interferomter (image attached).  I have theoretically calculated $L_c$ to be somewhere between 800-1200 $\mu m$ (equation on wiki page).  So anyways.

When I scan the movable mirror through a large range (50 mm), I observe interference fringes everywhere.  I thought that outside of the coherence length, there should be no interference.  Am I doing something incorrect?[image: Interferometer]

NOte: The top part of the MZI interferomter is an adjustable mirror.  NOT TO SCALE.

Comment: I don't understand your diagram.  It does not look like a Mach-Zehnder.  (A Michaelson would be better suited, I think.)  And a laser often has a coherence length much longer than 1 mm.  Why do you think that the coherence length is so small?  What kind of laser is it?  What are the rectangular things?  The object in the lower right looks like a mirror.  I suppose the object in the upper left is a beamsplitter.  Are the remaining two mirrors?  Which components move, and in which direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laser may be lasing on multiple modes (multiple longitudinal modes, multiple transverse modes, or both). Each of the individual modes may have a very long coherence length, while the many modes taken together would have a much shorter coherence length.

Suppose that one of the modes has, say, 40% of the power, and that four other modes have 15% of the power each. With a long path-length-difference, you will still easily see the fringes from the dominant mode interfering with itself.

This is a case where the temporal coherence properties of the laser are too complicated to properly describe using just one number called the "coherence length". If you plot fringe visibility vs path-length difference, it would *NOT* be a simple decaying exponential function.

Comment: OP:  what *do* you observe in your measurement?

Comment: What I measured was the intensity as I moved the adjustable mirror.  I realized that I was accidentally changing the path length at different locations, causing there to be fringes at the new location.  As for modes, there is a second with 5 percent of the power.  So my measurement was just a rookie mistake with adjusting the angle of the mirror in the bottom right.